# Using longer passwords with VNC?

Tags: passwords, vnc, authentication, tightvnc

`tightvncserver` limits VNC passwords to 8 characters, and even truncates them if one tries to enter a longer password.

My understanding is that this is (was?) due to compatibility issues, from what I can gather from posts online dating a few years.

Is this still the case – and if not, what can be done to allow longer passwords?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think you can change that limitation.
But to improve the security try using special characters, numbers and capital letters in your password